# User() got an unexpected keyword argument 'firstname'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

Hello I'm creating an API to register but I'm receiving this error

```
User() got an unexpected keyword argument 'firstname'
```

I tried many ways but couldn't fix, I'll be thankful if someone helps me fix this.
my code :

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()
# User Serializer
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name' ,'username', 'email', 'is_business')

# Register Serializer
class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id','first_name' ,'last_name' , 'username', 'brand', 'email', 'is_business', 'password')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(validated_data['username'],
                                            firstname=validated_data['first_name'],
                                            lastname=validated_data['last_name'],
                                            brand=validated_data['brand'],
                                            email=validated_data['email'],
                                            password=validated_data['password'])

        return user
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling with `firstname=` instead of `first_name=` which is probably the root cause

try something like

```py
    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(validated_data['username'],
                                            first_name=validated_data['first_name'],
                                            last_name=validated_data['last_name'],
                                            brand=validated_data['brand'],
                                            email=validated_data['email'],
                                            password=validated_data['password'])

        return user
```

Comment: Yes It did work bro thank you so much I don't know why I didn't notice that, I feel dumb

Comment: Glad I could help! Please accept the answer so that this question is marked answered :)